# How to filter by multiple lists in OpenERP?

Tags: python, list, odoo

How would you go about filtering one list based on a selection from a different list on the same page?

I'm trying to implement an interface similar to Warehouse Dashboard where multiple lists are on the same page but I need to filter each list based on a selection in the above list(s).

Thank you.

Comment: What do you call a "list" ? Are you talking of a multiple one2many inside a board ?

Comment: By list I meant the standard tree view where openerp shows the records from the database which can be searched and so on. I simply require to display many of these lists on one page and filter the content of them based on a selection on the previous list.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not possible. You should try to customize existing views and/or develop your own widget. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949936/how-to-start-developing-in-web-addons/11950556#11950556) on how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Moin you can fiter the `listview` when it display. But after display you can't filter the data on the bases of the other `listview`'s selection.